# Powershell - Extract excel - get user by UPN or MailAdresses

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory

As my previous questions,
I need to access to some excels data and get their `DisplayName`, `extensionAttribute15` and `UserPrincipalName` from an excel data file extracted from AAD,

here is my code:

```
Import-Module -Name ImportExcel
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

$results = @()

# Process each row in the Excel data
$result = foreach ($row in Import-Excel -Path "C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\DevicesWithInventory_08840cb2-4a3b-4e3e-a81e-6950ffac10f4.xlsx" -WorksheetName "Sheet1") {
    # Get the UPN from column 6 'hoeUiSC''Column 6'
    $userUPN = $row.'Primary user UPN'

    # Retrieve the user object from Active Directory
    # $user = Get-ADUser -Filter { mail -eq "$userUPN" } -Properties extensionAttribute15 | Select DisplayName,extensionAttribute15 #Export-csv C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\export1.csv
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -like "*$userUPN"} -Properties * | Select DisplayName,extensionAttribute15,UserPrincipalName #Export-csv C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\export1.csv
    if ($user) {
        # Create a custom object with the UPN and extensionAttribute15 value
         [PSCustomObject] @{
            UserPrincipalName    = $userUPN
            ExtensionAttribute15 = $user.extensionAttribute15
        }

        # Add the result to the array
        $results += $result
        Write-Host "User with UPN '$userUPN' found."
    } else {
        Write-Host "User with UPN '$userUPN' not found."
    }
}

# Export the results to a new Excel file
$results | Export-Excel -Path "C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\outputdata2.xlsx" -AutoSize -NoHeader

Write-Host
```

But actually, i got only my else string error message getting displayed : https://imgur.com/jMZQZZ4
and if i do an on-line research from PS, seems to display what i want: https://imgur.com/

I already tried to change `UserPrincipalName` to `mail`;`MailAdresses`;and even `DisplayName`(because i got a column with their DisplayName) but still got the same issue,
Could you help me to trigger that function ?
Thanks in advance

Try to get exported attributes from ADUser's account from mail, UPN or DisplayName, the script still display me an error message.
Thanks for your help

Comment: The ```-Filter``` parameter of ```Get-ADUser``` expects a ```[string]``` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps) but you're passing  a ```[ScriptBlock]``` - ```{UserPrincipalName -like "*$userUPN"}```. Powershell is being helpful by serialising your scriptblock to a string and passing *that* into ```Get-ADUser```, but it's *not* doing string interpolation on the value so it's passing the literal string ```UserPrincipalName -like "*$userUPN"```. Try a string instead - ```-Filter "UserPrincipalName -like `"*$userUPN`""```

Comment: @mclayton you are literaly a god to me rn,
thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module -Name ImportExcel
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

$results = @()

# Process each row in the Excel data DevicesWithInventory_08840cb2-4a3b-4e3e-a81e-6950ffac10f4.xlsx
$result = foreach ($row in Import-Excel -Path "C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\DevicesWithInventory_08840cb2-4a3b-4e3e-a81e-6950ffac10f4.xlsx" -WorksheetName "Sheet1") {
    # Get the UPN from column 6 'Column 6'
    $userUPN = $row.'Primary user UPN'
 # if (($row -eq $null) -or ($row -eq "") ){
    #    Write-Host "User with UPN '$userUPN' not found."
     #   }}
    # Retrieve the user object from Active Directory
    # $user = Get-ADUser -Filter { mail -eq "$userUPN" } -Properties extensionAttribute15 | Select DisplayName,extensionAttribute15 #Export-csv C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\export1.csv
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -like `"*$userUPN`"" -Properties * | Select DisplayName,extensionAttribute15,UserPrincipalName #Export-csv C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\export1.csv
    if (($user -ne $null) -or ($user -ne "")) {
        # Create a custom object with the UPN and extensionAttribute15 value
         [PSCustomObject] @{
            UserPrincipalName    = $userUPN
            ExtensionAttribute15 = $user.extensionAttribute15
        }

        # Add the result to the array
        $results += $result
        Write-Host "User with UPN '$userUPN' found."
    } 
    else {
        if (($user -eq $null) -or ($user -eq "") ){
        Write-Host "User with UPN '$userUPN' not found."
        }}
}

# Export the results to a new Excel file
$results | Export-Excel -Path "C:\Users\toulayoh\Downloads\outputdata23.xlsx" -AutoSize -NoHeader

Write-Host "Export complSeted successfully."
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).